# Explanation of rospy.Rate()

Tags: ros, rospy, documentation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am looking for an explanation of `rospy.rate()`, I have looked it in the documentation and it says the following:

> Convenience class for sleeping in a loop at a specified rate.

Can someone clarify this? What does it mean to sleep in a loop?

Documentation: http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/rospy/html/rospy.timer.Rate-class.html

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264812/explanation-of-rospy.rate()/) by [michaelszer](https://answers.ros.org/users/30470/michaelszer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2017-06-26

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-06-26**:
What's the link for the documentation that you're reading?

**Comment by [michaelszer](https://answers.ros.org/users/30470/michaelszer/) on 2017-06-26**:
I have added it to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From [`rospy` Time wiki entry](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Time#Sleeping_and_Rates),

> `rospy.Rate(hz)`
>
> rospy provides a rospy.Rate
> convenience class which makes a best
> effort at maintaining a particular
> rate for a loop. For example:
>
> ```
> r = rospy.Rate(10) # 10hz 
> while not rospy.is_shutdown():
>     pub.publish("hello")
>     r.sleep()
> ```
>
> In the above example, the `Rate`
> instance will attempt to keep the loop
> at 10hz by accounting for the time
> used by any operations during the
> loop. `Rate.sleep()` can throw a
> `rospy.ROSInterruptException` if the
> sleep is interrupted by shutdown.

Basically, it allows your loops to run at (nearly) the exact rate (in Hz) that you specify. It's a pretty standard way of looping with `ROS`. Check out the [source code](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/rospy/html/rospy.timer-pysrc.html#Rate.sleep) that's linked to in the documentation that you were looking at:

```
 87 -    def sleep(self): 
 88          """ 
 89          Attempt sleep at the specified rate. sleep() takes into 
 90          account the time elapsed since the last successful 
 91          sleep(). 
 92           
 93          @raise ROSInterruptException: if ROS shutdown occurs before 
 94          sleep completes 
 95          @raise ROSTimeMovedBackwardsException: if ROS time is set 
 96          backwards 
 97          """ 
 98          curr_time = rospy.rostime.get_rostime() 
 99          sleep(self._remaining(curr_time)) 
100          self.last_time = self.last_time + self.sleep_dur 
101   
102          # detect time jumping forwards, as well as loops that are 
103          # inherently too slow 
104          if curr_time - self.last_time > self.sleep_dur * 2: 
105              self.last_time = curr_time
```

Go through the [`rospy` tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Tutorials) if you haven't already. From the [writing a publisher and subscriber tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber):

> ```
> rate = rospy.Rate(10) # 10hz
> ```
>
> This line creates a `Rate` object `rate`. With the help of its method
> `sleep()`, it offers a convenient way
> for looping at the desired rate. With
> its argument of `10`, we should expect
> to go through the loop 10 times per
> second (as long as our processing time
> does not exceed 1/10th of a second!)

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 12

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [img5d](https://answers.ros.org/users/44236/img5d/) on 2019-07-24**:
good answer.

**Comment by [lxg](https://answers.ros.org/users/37572/lxg/) on 2020-08-06**:
thanks for the answer. but what happens if the process timing exceeds 1/10th of a second?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2020-08-06**:
That really shouldn't change anything as long as your computer can handle it

**Comment by [lxg](https://answers.ros.org/users/37572/lxg/) on 2020-08-07**:
Thanks jayes. so is it safe to conclude that all the code within the while loop above will execute 10 times a second as long as the computer can handle it? regardless of the code within the while loop?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2020-08-07**:
I wouldn't want to make any sweeping generalizations, but I'd say generally yes. If you examine the code above, *basically* what's happening is that a call to `r.sleep()` sleeps for the amount of time needed to keep the loop running at the given rate *as best as it can*.

**Comment by [lxg](https://answers.ros.org/users/37572/lxg/) on 2020-08-07**:
alright, thank you. Does r.sleep() trying to maintain the given rate have anything to do with python scripts running even after `Ctr + C` is pressed. I mean ROS definitely stops but the script keeps executing especially if there are loops within the while loop. especially data read from a buffer. Could it be related or is it an entirely different issue?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2020-08-08**:
I'd say probably not, but if this is an issue that you're having then you should post a question about it

**Comment by [lxg](https://answers.ros.org/users/37572/lxg/) on 2020-08-09**:
thanks. i did. and it got answered.